# React-Bootstrap I can't get Alert to appear when checking if user email is verified

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make it so that when I check whether a user has verified their email, an alert will appear asking to verify your email. I am not a fan of the regular pop up alert, so I was using the React-bootstrap alert to make something like this appear:

> You have yet to verify your email!

My console correctly logs whether a user is logged in and if the account is verified, but I can't get the alert to appear. Should I not make a `notVerifiedAlert` const? I've tried returning it directly, but it didn't make a difference. I'm not sure what is wrong because I am new to this and do not fully understand all concepts yet, so any help would be amazing.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';

class CheckVerification extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const notVerifiedAlert = (
            <Alert bsStyle="danger">
                <h4>Almost there...</h4>
                You have yet to verify your email!{' '}
                <strong>
                    {' '}
                    To access the survey it is required that you verify your email.
                </strong>{' '}
                Upon sign up an email was sent you. However, if you need a new
                verification sent to you click here. Once you verify your email, this
                alert will go away.
            </Alert>
        );

        return  (
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
              if (user) {
                console.log('This user is logged in.');
                if (!firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
                    notVerifiedAlert;
                    console.log('This user is not verified');
                } else {
                    console.log('This user is verified');
                }
             } else {
                console.log('This user is not logged in');
             }
         })

      );
    }
}

export default CheckVerification;
```

**update:** I figured out a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rethought my idea and rewrote it so if your email is not verified a specific page wont display. It's not perfect, but it works! :)

```
function sendLink(){
    firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
    alert("A verification email has been sent. Please go to your inbox now to verify you email. Refresh the page when complete.");
}

var fullID = '';

class SurveyPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: 'React'
        };
    }

//if email not verified, dont show iframe
    render() {
        if(!firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified){
            return(
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                <h5><strong>You must verify your email before viewing the survey.</strong></h5>
                    <a onClick={sendLink}> <u> Click here to send another verification email. </u> </a>
                    <br/>
                    <small> This alert will go away once your email is verified.</small>
                </div>
            )
        }
        else{

            fullID =  "https://airtable.com/embed/" + surveyID + "?backgroundColor=tealLight";

      console.log("Full survey URL: " + fullID);

            return (
                <div id = "content" >
                    <script src="https://static.airtable.com/js/embed/embed_snippet_v1.js" />
                    <IframeComponent
                        class="airtable-embed airtable-dynamic-height"
                        src= {fullID}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
  }
}
```